# Customizing the text output by the WordPress function human_time_diff()

Tags: php, wordpress

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff

I am using `human_time_diff()` to output relative dates on WordPress posts. e.g.

```
echo human_time_diff( get_the_time( 'U' ), current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) . ' ago';
```

This will output something like

```
34 mins ago
```

How can I change the wording so that the full word "minutes" is shown? e.g

```
34 minutes ago
```

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while looking for the same answer. I made a function which lets me neatly call `human_time_diff` with this simple code block: `<?php human_friendly_date(); ?>`. The answer to your question is in the second-to-last line of code.

```
function human_friendly_date() {
    global $post;
    $today = date("r");
    $postdate = get_the_time('r');
    $difference = round((strtotime($today) - strtotime($postdate))/(24*60*60),0);
        if ($difference >= 7) {
            $humandate = the_time('F j, Y');
        } else {
            $humandate = human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago';
        }
    $humandate = str_replace('mins', 'minutes', $humandate);
    echo $humandate;
}
```